# How to deploy a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

Say I have the Ballot Smart Contract on my Mist Remix IDE. Where do I go from there? I am completely lost. I compile the code. Then how do I deploy it. How do I provide the names for the proposals? How do I run this on the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in learning how to deploy your first smart contract using Remix, I recommend you read the ["Introduction" chapter of "Mastering Ethereum"](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/intro.asciidoc).

In that chapter they use Metamask as an Ethereum provider, giving you access to the Ropsten Test Network. From there, they show you how you can gain access to free Ether on the test network using the Metmask faucet. Finally, they walk you through building your own faucet contract in Remix, deploying, and testing that on the Ropsten network.

Here is the [faucet contract](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/first_edition/code/Faucet.sol) they help you deploy:

```
// Version of Solidity compiler this program was written for
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

// Our first contract is a faucet!
contract Faucet {

    // Give out ether to anyone who asks
    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {

        // Limit withdrawal amount
        require(withdraw_amount <= 100000000000000000);

        // Send the amount to the address that requested it
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }

    // Accept any incoming amount
    function () public payable {}

}
```